# Why my function fails to give correct outputs

Tags: r

I came up with a very simple function:

```
done <- function(x){
    x[x>1] <- NA
}
```

To test it, I created a variable:

```
test <- 0:10
```

and execute

```
done(test)
```

But it outputs the original test data, not giving any `NA`.

Comment: Add `return(x)` in your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined a return object:

```
done <- function(x){
  x[x>1] <- NA
  return(x)
}

test <- 0:10

done(test)
```

Another approach:

```
ifelse(test > 1, NA_integer_, test)
```